# Android - Playing Mp4

Tags: android, mp4, android-videoview

I am trying to play video files from http urls in my app. Why is that my app plays only certain mp4 files (I tried 512k mp4 and it worked), and doesn't play some others?

Here's the snippet of my code:

```
    mVideoView.setVideoPath(myVideoURL);
    mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    mVideoView.seekTo(currentPosition);
    mVideoView.requestFocus();
```

Thanks
Chris

Comment: I would like my app to be generic, so it can play as many different types of video files as possible, irrespective of size or encoding.

Mainly I am looking to play mp4 and 3gp files, buffer/no buffer, stream/no stream etc. What other ways are possible to achieve this, other than VideoView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your mp4's aren't DRM'd, and that they're not wider than 320 pixels (videoView will not scale them for you).  Are you getting any useful errors in LogCat?

Comment: Here's what LogCat shows me:

05-25 21:50:50.498: ERROR/QCOmxcore(51): OMXCORE API :  Free Handle fc87c
05-25 21:50:50.498: ERROR/QCOmxcore(51):  Unloading the dynamic library for OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc
05-25 21:50:50.508: ERROR/PlayerDriver(51): Command PLAYER_PREPARE completed with an error or info PVMFErrNoResources
05-25 21:50:50.508: ERROR/MediaPlayer(15981): error (1, -15)
05-25 21:50:50.508: ERROR/MediaPlayer(15981): Error (1,-15)

How can I make sure to set the VideoView width to 320 pixels?

Comment: It isn't a matter of setting the VideoView width (it is automatically determined by the container its' in) - the actual mp4 video width has to be 320 pixels.  You can't play videos larger than 320 pixels wide (you can probably play smaller ones, I'm not sure)

Comment: So there is no way to play videos larger than 320 pixels on android?

Comment: Not with VideoView (at least at the moment - you gotta figure that's an oversight).  This is especially annoying now that some Android phones have screens larger than 320 pixels wide.  There may or may not be some newer things in 2.1/2.2/2.x that you could poke around in, but VideoView is basically unchanged since 1.5.

Comment: I would like my app to be generic, so it can play as many different types of video files as possible, irrespective of size or encoding. Mainly I am looking to play mp4 and 3gp files, buffer/no buffer, stream/no stream etc. What other ways are possible to achieve this, other than VideoView?

Comment: Sadly I don't know of any, but admittedly video isn't my focus.  Perhaps if you google around or plumb through the Android docs you might find some other API or library that does video.