# VideoView MP4 isn't working

Tags: android

I've been struggling to make VideoView work with mp4 files. The thing is that with some mp4 files (that have lower resolution) it works, but in case of higher resolution 480x268 it rejects to play. This issue resembles me the same situation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910292/android-playing-mp4). It's said that Android can only play mp4 files below certain resolution. Does it holds for today ?

P.S. I'm building  against Android 2.3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

did u add the hardware support while creating the emulator for playing video and audio. Maybe thats y it isnt working

Comment: I've tested it on real phones. It seems that <= 2.3. is unable to play it for some reason.

Comment: it could even be due to the files being corrupt at times.